# Help me to understand following points about the strategy pattern, how it relates to open/closed principle

Tags: design-patterns, object-oriented-design

I am learning design patterns. I read [this](http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy) article. Point no. 3 is not clear to me. The writer said that **strategy lets you change the guts of an object**. But this is a violation of the [**open-close** principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Closed_Principle). Am I wrong? If I am wrong, then help me to understand what writer wanted to describe.

1. Strategy is like Template Method except in its granularity.
2. State is like Strategy except in its intent.
3. Strategy lets you change the guts of an object. Decorator lets you change the skin.
4. State, Strategy, Bridge (and to some degree Adapter) have similar solution structures.
5. They all share elements of the ‘handle/body’ idiom. They differ in intent - that is,   they solve different problems.
6. Strategy has 2 different implementations, the first is similar to State. The difference is in binding times (Strategy is a bind-once pattern, whereas State is more dynamic).
   Strategy objects often make good Flyweights.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Strategy lets you change the guts of an object. But it is the violation of open-close principle. Am I wrong??

No, the opposite is the case, it is **a standard example** for the OCP. In the shown example, you change or extend the behaviour of `TransportationToAirport` (open for extensions) without modifying this class (closed for modifications). Just derive a new `Strategy` object (like `Train`) and use it in conjunction with your unmodified `TransportationToAirport` object.

Comment: Actually the word "guts" makes me confused. Now I am little bit clear. Thanks for response.

Comment: +1 though when extending you have to be careful not to violate the Liskov Substitution Principle (LSP) - ie you can't go "against" the class you are extending from.

Comment: @MarjanVenema: yes, but this is not very special for the strategy pattern - LSP should be always considered when using inheritance.